# Custom textview with rotate, zoom in,zoom out and move on touch in android?

Tags: android, scale, textview, multi-touch, translate

Any buddy have Custom Text View with Rotate, Zoom In, Zoom Out & Move functionality like MutiTouch Image View like this http://judepereira.com/blog/multi-touch-in-android-translate-scale-and-rotate/ in android?
I Want exactly like this screen shots.
1. In that screen draw simple text.
2. In that screen when i zoom this view Text auto wrap.
3. In that screen Move Text on view.
4. In that screen Rotate Text.
This all functionality do on TextView touch.

[image: draw simple text]

[image: zoom this view Text auto wrap][image: Move Text on view][image: Rotate Text]

Comment: Since you are linking to a library/code that does what you need, what seems to be the problem?

Comment: @Alex I want exactly like that link which i provide in question but in this link there is ImageView & I want this for TextView.

Comment: Hi @ravi152, are you complete you project?

Comment: No @ biswajitGhosh still i dint solve this issue

Comment: Hey @ravi152 , did you receive this issue ?

Comment: @biswajitGhosh no i still not find any perfcat solution of this

Comment: Any luck guy, this is what I want know. If you guys have solution, please share it

Comment: @ravi152 have you found any solution4

Answer (score 6):

I used https://github.com/jcmore2/Collage to achieve a rotated textview

but i changed the whole code since the plugin works with images 
**CardView extends ImageView**
i chnaged to **MyCardView extends RelativeLayout** then removed all the code related to images
and instead of using **collage.createCollageResources(listRes);**
i created my own function in my own **CollageView** class

```
public void createCollage(List<MyCardView> list) {
    for (MyCardView layout : list) {
        addCard(layout);
    }
}
```

Now in the Activity you can add to the collageview a complete RelativeLayout with it's children not just images

this also will allow dealing with single view or multiple .. TextView or any thing else .. finally this will make the view not just rotated but dragged and zoomed with multi touch gesture.

[image]

[image]

Comment: hey can you give code for textview i am really stuck in this

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can create it see below image and follow [**Here.**](https://github.com/niravkalola/Android-StickerView)

**ImageView:**  To add ImageView

```
    // add a stickerImage to canvas
    StickerImageView iv_sticker = new StickerImageView(MainActivity.this);
    iv_sticker.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.c10));
    canvas.addView(iv_sticker);
```

**TextView:** To add TextView

```
    // add a stickerText to canvas
    StickerTextView tv_sticker = new StickerTextView(MainActivity.this);
    tv_sticker.setText("nkDroid");
    canvas.addView(tv_sticker);
```

However, build this did an awesome job.

[image]

Comment: The link does not open.