# scale text with bounded area and move textview on image by freehand in android

Tags: android, scale, move

I want to scale text view with bounded area and bounded text view move on image view by freehand.

[Actually, I want exactly like that link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28831831/custom-textview-with-rotate-zoom-in-zoom-out-and-move-on-touch-in-android)

but nobody help regarding that question

please help me how to solve that problem specially bounded text view with movement on image view in android.

my code :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

TextView scaleGesture;
ScaleGestureDetector scaleGestureDetector;

private View selected_item = null;
private int offset_x = 0;
private int offset_y = 0;

Bitmap bitmap;
LinearLayout view1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity);
    scaleGesture = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    scaleGesture.setText("this is some text how do you do?");
    scaleGestureDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(this,
            new simpleOnScaleGestureListener());

    ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.vg);
    vg.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            scaleGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

            if (selected_item != null) {
                switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    int x = (int) event.getX() - offset_x;
                    int y = (int) event.getY() - offset_y;
                    //
                    int w = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
                            .getWidth() - 100;
                    int h = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
                            .getHeight() - 100;
                    if (x > w)
                        x = w;
                    if (y > h)
                        y = h;
                    if (x < 0)
                        x = 0;
                    if (y < 0)
                        y = 0;
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                            new ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams(
                                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    lp.setMargins(x, y, 0, 0);

                    selected_item.setLayoutParams(lp);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
    // TextView img = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    scaleGesture.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                offset_x = (int) event.getX();
                offset_y = (int) event.getY();
                selected_item = v;
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

// @Override
// public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
// // TODO Auto-generated method stub
// scaleGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
// return true;
// }

public class simpleOnScaleGestureListener extends
        SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        float size = scaleGesture.getTextSize();
        Log.d("TextSizeStart", String.valueOf(size));

        float factor = detector.getScaleFactor();
        Log.d("Factor", String.valueOf(factor));

        float product = size * factor;
        Log.d("TextSize", String.valueOf(product));
        scaleGesture.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, product);

        size = scaleGesture.getTextSize();
        Log.d("TextSizeEnd", String.valueOf(size));
        return true;
    }
}
```

layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/vg"
    android:layout_width="500dp"
    android:layout_height="500dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Static ZoomControls"
        android:textColor="#4169E1"
        android:textSize="18dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```